# Bundling React 18 Client/Server Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, rollupjs

I have a set of React components written with TypeScript that I would like to bundle to a component library to use primarily with Next.js 13. I would like them to be able to be imported from the base package (e.g `import { Button } from 'my-package'`) and therefore the bundle needs to be tree-shakable.

From the research I have done, it seems that using something like Rollup or Webpack would be the way to bundle them, but I'm not sure how it would work with the `'use client'` directives present in some component files. It seems like they would either all be server components (and many features not work) or all client components (which is really not ideal).

In my previous attempts at using Rollup, I was also unable to get tree-shaking to work, resulting in a massive bundle sent to the client.

How can I bundle them in a way that allows them to be tree-shaken while also preserving the benefits of both client and server components?